# Keep div aspect ratio when scaling, with inner images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-scaling

I've been trying to build a menu with a fixed aspect-ratio that is scaled according to the size of the browser window. For this I am using a div with a background image like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/keroben/9seaM/

I am using the following trick with padding-bottom to keep the aspect ratio:

```
padding-bottom:10%;
```

from [Keeping/scaling DIV Ratio with percentages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066350/keeping-scaling-div-ratio-with-percentages/).

This works when resizing and keeps the aspect ratio. Now when I add the menu entries as images, I can't get it right that the height of the div stays the same (http://jsfiddle.net/keroben/aT3Vz/):

```
<div id="cool" >
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18518333/clear.png"/>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18518333/clear.png"/>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18518333/clear.png"/>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18518333/clear.png"/>    
</div>
```

I've tried various other techniques too, but nothing works. I'm starting to think that I can only get this to work by setting the width and height directly in javascript, but I'd like to know if there's a more elegant solution...

Comment: `<img />` elements are good at maintaining their own aspect ratio, can you rely on the image elements to give height to the containing `<div />`?

Comment: @Jasper, yeah I thought so too, but with several images the default seems to just align them vertically when the horizontal space is not enough anymore regardless of a fixed height I might have set. I was stuck a long time with fluid imagess `max-width:100%` until I realized several images are different. I think Horatio's and Maciej's answers work though and I'll accept one of them after I've had time to test later...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the images change the height of the div. You can keep them from doing that by floating them. Also, if you want them to always fit within the container, you'll need to adjust the width of the images. So, something like this might work:

```
#cool img {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    height: auto;
}
```

In the interest of creating semantic HTML, you may want to change your markup to something more like the following:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/my/cool/image.png" alt="Menu item 1"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/my/cool/image.png" alt="Menu item 2"/></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="/my/cool/image.png" alt="Menu item 3"/></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: also `display: block`. this is what you are looking for

Comment: You are right. Though in most browsers, adding a float causes an implicit `display:block`.

Comment: I didn't know that. I have to read about it, but I think in firefox it doesn't work in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this

`#cool img{display:block;float:left;width:25%;height:auto;}`

here you have example:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maciekpaprocki/aT3Vz/2/)